# Two or more tinymce editors

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I'm currently developing a plugin in which i need two tiny_mce editors on the same (post-new.php) page.
Any hint?
Please please please!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This will replace all textareas with a tinymce-editor (see mode).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "textareas",
    theme : "advanced",
    plugins : "imagemanager,safari,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,wordcount,simplebrowser",

    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
    theme_advanced_resizing : true,

    // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
    content_css : "../css/custom.css",

});
```